Renormalization Effective Field Theory for Non-renormalizable Theory: RG running for Prediction?
It is well-known that the non-renormalizable theory doesn't have predictable effect, this is because there are infinite numbers of counter terms absorbing infinite number of divergence emerging in higher order correction.
For example, consider following effective field theory running with power counting $\mathcal{O}(E/\Lambda)$, where $E$ is the experiment energy scale and $\Lambda$ is the energy cutoff.
\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}(\partial \phi)^2+\frac{1}{2}(\partial \varphi)^2 - \frac{\lambda}{4!}\phi^4 - \frac{c}{\Lambda^2} (\partial \phi)^2\varphi^2
\end{equation}
Where we can see that the last term is a dim-6 operator with dimensionless Wilson coefficient $c$ and the minus dimension $1/\Lambda^2$, which means it is a non-renomalizable theory.
If we start renormalizing whatsoever, we find that 1-loop $\phi\phi\varphi\varphi$ would require $\mathcal{O}(1/\Lambda^2)$ order counter term.
But if we further consider 1-loop $\varphi\varphi\varphi\varphi$ would require $\mathcal{O}(1/\Lambda^4)$, which is dim-8 counter term.
In EFT point of view, we require our theory precision up to energy scale $\mathcal{O}(1/\Lambda^2)$, that is, we discard the dim-8 counter term.
This allows us to run the coupling constant with RGE without worries, because we only require correction up to dim-6 counter term.
But, does this mean, requiring our theory precision only up to $\mathcal{O}(1/\Lambda^2)$, we can still have prediction by RG running for non-renormalizable theory?

IR scaling (zooming out) is generally more forgiving than UV scaling, at least in local/causal theories: there can be zillions of terms in your Lagrangian, but only a few will be IR-relevant (i.e. the extra terms will be suppressed by inverse powers of the length scale.) Also, "zooming out" in space magnifies locality, so you're less likely to have to worry about IR divergent integral operators.
